What distinguishes boosts from general Lorentz transformations?
It's known that every element of the restricted Lorentz group  $SO^+(1,3)$ (the identity component of the Lorentz group) can be written uniquely as the product of a spatial rotation and a boost. But I din't find any general method in the literature to factorize a general element of $SO^+(1,3)$ to a boost and a rotation.  Is there such a method? Or, asking otherwise, how can I check whether an element of $SO^+(1,3)$ is a pure boost in some direction, a pure spatial rotation, or the combination of these two?

Do you know how to compute eigenvalues?

@MoisheKohan What can i do with eigenvectors here?

They (eigenvalues) will tell you exactly what type of Lorentz transformation you have. Start by comparing (complex) eigenvalues of a boost and of a rotation.

@MoisheKohan We are in a 4-dimensional real vector space. What are complex eigenvalues?

Roots of the characteristic polynomial. This you typically learn in an undergraduate linear algebra class.

@MoisheKohan Thanks, you gave me a useful keyword to search for. I think I should study this question and the answers to it.

A good case to work out is the 1d space case. That tells you exactly what boosts are.

@Deane 1d space doesn't have nontrivial rotation, so there every proper Lorentz transformation is a boost.

Yes, that’s my point. A transformation is a pure boost if you can choose a basis such that it looks like a 1d boost.

Here is a more geometric answer.
Any 2D subspace of Minkowski space can be categorized as space-like or time-like. For convenience I will call such a subspace a "plane" without mentioning it also has to pass through the origin. I will assume metric signature $(+---)$; it's easy to translate to $(-+++)$ if desired.
Let $v^2 = v\cdot v$ for any vector $v$ denote the space-time magnitude, i.e. if $v = (t,x,y,z)$ then $v^2 = t^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2$. A space-like plane is one in which you can find two orthogonal space-like vectors, i.e. $v,w$ such that $v\cdot w = 0$ and $v^2,w^2 < 0$. A time-like plane is one in which you can find two orthogonal vectors, one time-like and one space-like, i.e. $v\cdot w = 0$, $v^2>0$, and $w^2<0$; or equivalently two non-orthogonal light-like vectors, i.e. $v\cdot w\ne0$ and $v^2=w^2=0$. (It happens that in Minkowski space two non-parallel light-like vectors cannot be orthogonal, so it is enough to find such a pair.)
An orthogonal transformation is a linear transformation $T$ that preserves the metric, i.e. $T(v)\cdot T(w) = v\cdot w$ for all $v,w$. Such a transformation necessarily has determinant $\pm1$; we say it is orientation-preserving if the determinant is $+1$.
A spatial rotation is an orientation-preserving orthogonal transformation that fixes a space-like plane $P$ but is the identity on its orthogonal complement, i.e. $T(p)\in P$ for all $p\in P$ but $T(q) = q$ for all $q\in P^\perp$.
A boost is an orientation-preserving orthogonal transformation that fixes a time-like plane but is the identity on its orthogonal complement.

In terms of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we get the following:
An orthogonal transformation $T$ is a spatial rotation if it has eigenvalues $1,1,z,\bar z$ with $z$ complex and $|z|=1$. This is essentially the same as in 3-space.
An orthogonal transformation $T$ is a boost if it has eigenvalues $1,1,\lambda,1/\lambda$ for some real $\lambda$ and such that the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda,1/\lambda$ are both light-like. This is because if $v$ is light like then $T(v)^2 = v^2 = 0$ so $T(v)$ is also light-like; and the defining fixed plane $P$ above has only two light like lines.

Not quite, you are conflating elliptic and loxodromic transformations. To get elliptics you should add $|z|=1$.

@MoisheKohan That makes sense, thanks for pointing that out.

I don't know of any specific literature, but I do have something in my own personal notes about the decomposition, and no references, so bear with me:
If $P$ is a Lorentz Matrix (not necessarily in the restricted Lorentz group) written as
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
a & {\bf b}^T \\
{\bf d} & M
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where ${\bf b},{\bf d}$ are 3-vectors and $M$ is a $3x3$ matrix, then if we define
$$
{\bf u}=-\frac{c}{a}{\bf b},\;\;\;\;R=M-\frac{{\bf db}^T}{a+1},\;\;\;\;\gamma=a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}}
$$
we have that $u=|{\bf u}|<c$, $R$ is orthogonal, and
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & R
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma & -\gamma\frac{{\bf u}^T}{c} \\
-\gamma\frac{{\bf u}}{c} & I+\frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma+1}\frac{{\bf uu}^T}{c^2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You can check this directly, although it is a pain and just symbol crunching.
This decomposition:

is unique provided the rotation acts second; if the rotation acts first, we have a similar unique decomposition
is the product of a rotation and a boost

From here, we can examine our quick check to determine if a Lorentz matrix is a pure boost. If we have a pure boost, then $R=I$. Thus,
$$
R=I\iff M-\frac{{\bf db}^T}{a+1}=I
$$
This gives a direction computation (in terms of matrices) to determine if a Lorentz matrix is a pure boost. The case of a pure rotation comes from the fact that the velocity $\bf u$ depends on $\bf b$; if ${\bf b}={\bf 0}$, then the matrix is a pure rotation.
If you are concerned about the fact that these are for general Lorentz matrices and not special Lorentz matrices, don't worry. The boost always has a determinant of 1, so the only concern is the orthogonal matrix $R$. If we are working with the special Lorentz group, then $R$ always comes out with a positive determinant.

A Lorentz transformation, at least in the largest chart around the identity, is the exponential of a linear combination of three $1\otimes\sigma_i$ and the three $\alpha_i=\sigma_1\otimes \sigma_i$ matrices in the $\gamma$ algebra with $\gamma_i \gamma_k-\gamma_k \gamma_i \ = \ 2  g_{ik} \mathbb 1$.
So the equation to be solved is
$$e^{\vec u \cdot \vec \alpha + \vec \phi \cdot \vec \sigma}=e^{\vec v \cdot \vec \alpha} \cdot e^{ \vec \theta \cdot \vec \sigma}$$ with a pure imaaginary vector $\phi$ denoting axis of rotation and its norm representing the angle.
The six equations for the parameters $\vec v,\ \vec \theta$ are determined by the projections
$$\text{Tr}\left( \sigma_k   e^{\vec u \cdot \vec \alpha + \vec \phi \cdot \vec \sigma}\right)=\text{Tr} \left(\sigma_k e^{\vec v \cdot \vec \alpha} \cdot e^{ \vec \theta \cdot \vec \sigma}\right)$$
and the same for $\alpha_k$ yielding a set of trigonometric equations in the squares of the parameters.
Example in Mathematica in the standard Dirac algebra
  MatrixExp[ a Subscript[\[Alpha], 1] + \[Phi] Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]] //
  FullSimplify // MatrixForm

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \cosh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}\right) & -\frac{i \phi  \sinh
   \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} & 0 &
   \frac{a \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}} \\
 \frac{i \phi  \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} & \cosh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right) & \frac{a \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{a \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} & \cosh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right) & -\frac{i \phi  \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} \\
 \frac{a \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}} & 0 & \frac{i \phi  \sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} & \cosh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$= \cosh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi^2}\right)\ \  \mathbb 1 + 
\frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{a^2+\phi
   ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+\phi ^2}} \ 
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & - i \phi  & 0 & a \\
 i \phi   & 0 &  a  & 0 \\
 0 &  a  & 0 & - i \phi  \\
 a  & 0 &  i \phi   & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$
The exponential is a linear combination in the $\gamma$ algebra
including the unit by  the identity $$(m\cdot \alpha +n.\sigma )^2=m^2+n^2 +i\  \ \alpha \cdot m\times n$$
$$e^{\vec n \cdot \sigma} = \cosh (|\vec n|) + \vec n \cdot \sigma \ \sinh (|\vec n|) $$
Since the angular vector $\phi$ is pure imaginary, the group manifold splits by the sign of $a^2+\phi^2$ into rotations with a smaller boost and boost with a smaller rotation vector.
